# Can a scaling factor be entered from keyboard

Tags: uv-image-editor

When scaling a material in uv editing (press S key and drag using LMB down) is it possible to enter a particular value using the keyboard rather than simply try to drag the mouse to a value and try and get a particular value?
I am using a material of a wooden plank which has 7 planks on it and would like to try and end up with 45 full planks on the model which is 9 metres long.

Comment: Hi :). There's a small menu bottom left, that allows to enter precise values

Comment: Thanks Jachym. What is the name of the small menu bottom left? I am using 2.92, assume you mean in the uv editing 'panel' but I don't see any menu bottom left.    I can simply enter a value after pressing S (key) to rescale on both X and Y which is what I want.

Comment: Hi :). It only pops-up once you scale something, so you can adjust the values.

Comment: Thanks Jachym (Resize - I see it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just press <kbd>S</kbd> and enter the scaling number instead of dragging the mouse.

If you just want to scale x direction - press: <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> (would scale only x axis by 2)

Comment: For completeness, `Y` or `Z` could allow you to scale on those axes too. This also works with grabbing and rotation, and in fact a lot of operations.

Comment: Thanks Krolton. I will add that to my ever growing list (document) of tips.